# Spring Data MongoDB: Update document based on multiple identifiers with Composite ID vs. MongoTemplate upsert vs. MongoRepository find & save

Tags: java, design, spring, mongodb

I'm wondering for best practices to upsert a document based on two identifiers.

```java
@Document(collection = "cars")
public class CarEntity {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String color;
    private String brand;
    private Instant repairedAt;
        ...
}
```

Each car is identifiable with the combination of `color` and `brand`, which is the logical ID to upsert a document. I want to update the `repairedAt` field.

Now there are (to my knowledge) three good ways to handle that.

**Option 1:** Custom repository with custom `upsertOneByColorAndBrand` which **either**

1.a) uses the `CarRepository` internally:

```java
public void upsertOneByColorAndBrand(final CarEntity carNew,
                                           final String color,
                                           final String brand) {
    // findOneByColorAndBrand is no custom implementation, just from the interface
    var carExisting = repo.findOneByColorAndBrand(color, brand);
    if (carExisting == null) {
        // write to DB if not existent
        repo.save(carNew);
    } else {
        // update document if existing
        carExisting.setRepairedAt(carNew.getRepairedAt());
        repo.save(carExisting);
    }
}
```

1.b) **or** uses `MongoTemplate` internally:

```java
public void upsertOneByColorAndBrand(final CarEntity carNew,
                                           final String color,
                                           final String brand) {
    // define find query
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("color").is(color));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("brand").is(brand));

    // create document from entity
    Document doc = new Document();
    mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(carNew, doc);
    Update update = Update.fromDocument(doc);

    // upsert
    mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, CarEntity.class);
}
```

**Option 2:** You could also skip the whole custom repository implementation and just define the ID of the document yourself, based on the combination of `color` & `brand`, as the combination of these are unique in this example. When doing that, you can just use the native `repo.save(car)`, as it will automagically use the new composite ID to operate, which skips the whole "find" part.

I compared the performance of option 1.a and option 1.b and the difference is in the milliseconds for a three digit amount of documents. That's because 1.a) splits up the "find" and "save" operation.

Are there huge downsides/benefits with option 2? In your experience, is using a composite ID in the Spring Data environment a good idea? Would you rather use compound indexes or "set" the ID manually when creating the entity?